# How can I properly setup Flutter on Windows?

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

I'm having issues in my new flutter installation tried few things but nothing worked.
This is the view of my `flutter doctor` output:

> [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 33.0.2)
> • Android SDK at C:\Users\My PC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
> X cmdline-tools component is missing
> Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
> See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
> X Android license status unknown.
> Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
> See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for
> more details.
>
> [√] Chrome - develop for the web
> • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
>
> [X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
> X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
> Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
> Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
> • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
> • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
> https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
> • Dart plugin can be installed from:
> https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-9505619)
>
> [√] VS Code (version 1.76.2)
> • VS Code at C:\Users\My PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
> • Flutter extension version 3.60.0
>
> [√] Connected device (3 available)
> • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2604]
> • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 111.0.5563.65
> • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 111.0.1661.41
>
> [√] HTTP Host Availability
> • All required HTTP hosts are available

Tried uninstalling android studio and updating path

Answer (score 0):

Try to install those two (SDK and Build Tools):

[image: SDK]

[image: And CMD tools]

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue:

> [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2) • Android SDK at C:\Users\My PC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk X cmdline-tools component is missing Run path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest" See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details. X Android license status unknown. Run flutter doctor --android-licenses to accept the SDK licenses. See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

Open Android Studio go to `SDK Manager` then under `SDK Tools` tab tick `Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)` then click `Apply` button. It will then download and install the Android SDK Command-line Tools. After that click `Ok` and close Android Studio. Then from Windows Terminal run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`, accept all the licenses. To check run `flutter doctor` again. This issue should be solved.

For the second issue:

> [X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development. Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/. Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

On Windows Flutter uses Visual Studio to compile applications. Therefore you need to install Visual Studio. You can find Visual Studio Community from Microsoft by searching for "Visual Studio Community".

Please check this link for further details, [Windows setup][1].

Just to be sure you can run `flutter doctor` again. You should have everything set.
[1]: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows

Answer (score 0):

[image: install this]You need to install cmdline tools in order to use flutter ,after that you need to accept android-licenses using `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and accept all the licenses

Comment: thank you but visual studio installation can I skip it ?

Comment: no still you need to install that